# String class Performance Issue

Tags: java, string, performance, performance-testing

String is immutable, Every immutable object in Java is thread safe ,that implies String is also thread safe . String can not be used by two threads simultaneously.

StringBuffer is mutable, but each method in StringBuffer is synchronized that is StringBuffer is thread safe . so **Performance is slow**.

then My Query is String has any performance issue?

Comment: Are you asking about performance issues related explicitly to concatenation?

Comment: "String can not be used by two threads simultaneously." Um, yes it can, precisely because it *is* immutable. You're mistaking "thread-safe" for "requires locking". So the premise of the question is broken - and if it weren't, it would be too broad, really.

Comment: "String can not be used by two threads simultaneously" - what makes you say this?  Do you have any reference?

Comment: Immutable objects are always thread-safe. Right? If it is thread safe how two threads can access a resource.

Comment: "If it is thread safe how two threads can access a resource." Um, by reading it? What do you think is *stopping* two threads accessing it at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Immutable doesn't imply you can't use the same String in multiple threads at the same time. It means it's internal state can't be changed after being instanciated contrary to StringBuffer for exemple where calling `append` changes your buffer's internal state.

This means it's thread safe by design.

The performance of StringBuffer is low (opposed to the performance of StringBuilder) because it requires locking the object before each operation on it's internal state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not a real programming problem, but simply you have a bad logic.

For a `StringBuffer`

- StringBuffer is synchronized
- Because its methods are synchronized, therefore its methods won't run simultaneously in two threads
- Because its methods won't run simultaneously in two threads, therefore it is thread safe
- Because methods are synchronized, therefore performance is bad compared with non-synchronized counterpart.

However, the above does not implies the vice-versa like :

- Because it is thread-safe, it won't run simultaneous in two threads
- Because it is thread-safe, its performance is bad (compared with non-thread-safe counterpart)

Synchronization/locking is only one of many ways to achieve thread-safety.

Answer (score -2):

No there is no performance issue with String , Because String is immutable , each time one process can use it and by thread safe in nature no one can change it .

While `StringBuffer`  is mutable so multiple process uses single `StringBuffer`  object with cost of synchronization . that's why performance of `StringBuffer` is slow.

**Processes**

A process has a self-contained execution environment. A process generally has a complete, private set of basic run-time resources; in particular, each process has its own memory space.

**Threads**

Threads are sometimes called lightweight processes. Both processes and threads provide an execution environment, but creating a new thread requires fewer resources than creating a new process.

Comment: Threads and processes are entirely different - and "each time one process can use it" makes little sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: @JonSkeet So what ,Thread is itself a process , parallel to other process.